# Trying to use isset to set value but still get error

Tags: php, cart, isset

I am very new to php, and trying to create a cart page.

Iv got the product Id, Option and Price being sent using the $_POST array.

I want the `$ino` to hold the value for Id- which i  does.

I'm getting one recurring error.

> Notice: Undefined index: 3 in /home/sl0/s3196040/public_html/wp/a3/cart.php on line 84 
>   Name: Notice: Undefined index: 3 in /home/sl0/s3196040/public_html/wp/a3/cart.php on line 71
>   Price: Notice: Undefined index: 3 in /home/sl0/s3196040/public_html/wp/a3/cart.php on line 74**

I know i am suppose to "isset" $ino to check if its set or not, but i thought i have ?

If i type the value manually in like `$pumps[3]['Title']` it works, but fails if i use the $ino variable like this `$pumps[$ino]['Title']`.

This is in the $_POST Array ( [Id] => 3 [option] => english [qty] => 3

```
define("TITLE", "Product Page");

include_once('tools.php');
topModule('Business Name - Home', 'showSpecials()');

print_r($pumps[3]['Price']);
print_r($_POST);

// if i have the ID of the product, i need to turn it into a variables that the cart can display

if (isset ( $_POST ['Id'] )) {
    // Check the item is not already in the cart
    if (!in_array($_POST ["Id"], $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        // Add new item to cart
        $_SESSION ['cart'][] = $_POST["Id"];
    }
}

else if (isset ( $_POST ['delete'] )) { // a remove button has been clicked
    // Remove the item from the cart
    if (false !== $key = array_search($_POST['delete'], $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }

    // Empty Cart
    else if (isset ( $_POST ["delete"] )) { // remove item from cart
        unset ( $_SESSION ['cart'] );      
    }
}

if (isset ( $_SESSION ["cart"] )) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $ino = $_POST['submit'];
    }
?>

<form action='(omitted link)'
target='_blank' method='post'
enctype=''>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
<?php
// Set a default total
$total = 0;
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $ino ) {
    ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        Name: <?php echo $pumps[$ino]['Title']; ?>  // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        Price: <?php echo $pumps[$ino]['Price']; ?> // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        Qty: <?php echo $_POST[$ino]['qty']; ?>  // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type='submit' name='delete' value='<?php echo $ino; ?>'>Remove</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    $total += $pumps[$ino]['Price']; // error here
} // end foreach
?>

Total: $<?php echo $total; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total: $<?php echo($total); ?></td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='Checkout' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type='submit' name='clear'>Clear cart</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php  } ?>


<?php
  endModule(); // Now a function call
?>
```

The contents of my `$pumps` array

```
Array
(


   [1] => Array
        (
            [OID] => 01PRO
            [Title] => ProphetX
            [Description] => The Sequential Prophet X is a potent fusion of samples-plus-synthesis and is Dave Smith�s most ground-breaking evolution of the Prophet yet.
            [Option] => 
            [Price] => $4,500 
            [Image] => 
        )
[2] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 03REV
        [Title] => ProphetRev 2
        [Description] => The Prophet Rev2 is Dave Smith�s reimagining of his Prophet �08 poly synth � a modern classic that has appeared on countless recordings and stages since its debut in 2007
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $3,000 
        [Image] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 03REV
        [Title] => Rev2 Desktop
        [Description] => The Prophet Rev2 desktop module is just as powerful and easy to use as its counterpart, the Prophet Rev2 keyboard.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $2,500 
        [Image] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 04OB6
        [Title] => OB-6 
        [Description] => The OB-6� is a once-in-a-lifetime collaboration between the two most influential designers in poly synth history, Dave Smith and Tom Oberheim.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $2,000 
        [Image] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 05OB6
        [Title] => OB-6 Desktop
        [Description] => The OB-6� desktop module is just as powerful and easy to use as its counterpart, the OB-6 Keyboard.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $1,500 
        [Image] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 06PR6
        [Title] => Prophet 6
        [Description] => The Prophet-6 is Dave Smith�s tribute to the poly synth that started it all�the Sequential Prophet-5. But it�s not simply a reissue of a classic. Rather, as Dave puts it, �It�s the result of our effort to build the most awesome-sounding, modern analog poly synth possible.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $3,500 
        [Image] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 07PR6
        [Title] => Prophet 6 Desktop
        [Description] => The Prophet-6 desktop module is every bit as powerful and easy to use as its counterpart, the Prophet-6 Keyboard. The module has all of the same controls as the keyboard version and provides the same immediacy and ease of use � with absolutely no menu diving. As with the Prophet-6 Keyboard, all parameters are at your fingertips, with full-sized knobs and switches and a comfortable, intuitive layout.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $2,000 
        [Image] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 08PR2
        [Title] => Pro 2 
        [Description] => The Pro 2 is Dave Smith�s flagship mono synth, and as Dave himself puts it, his �most powerful mono synth ever.�
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $4,000 
        [Image] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [OID] => 09TEM
        [Title] => Tempest 
        [Description] => Tempest is the brainchild of legendary instrument designers, Dave Smith and Roger Linn.
        [Option] => 
        [Price] => $3,000 
        [Image] => 
    )

)
```

The contents of `$_SESSION['cart']`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 9 
)
```

Code is messy but its just for learning purposes, thanks!

Comment: An error like that always means that you try to use an element in the array that does not exists. Can you post the other code you have in your include? To check those variables that you use.

Comment: Because array $ino start indexing from 0, but your session $_SESSION['cart'] don't have any value on index 0.

Comment: _sidenote_: what is that habit of closing and opening php tags all the time about?

Comment: $ino does contain a value though, it contains the product ID, which i get from $_POST

Comment: @n0rad, could you add the contents of `$_SESSION['cart']` and `$pumps` to your answer?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort updated! :)

Comment: @n0rad, what is the value of the first element? Is it an empty string?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort its empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails on line 71 which is `<?php echo $_POST[$ino]['qty']; ?>` so your `$pumps` variable is fine, but your $_POST variable does not contain a key with the value of `$ino`. So you will have to check this variable and change your index accordingly.

Also the line with `$ino = $_POST['submit'];` has no effect because you overwrite this variable with `foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $ino )`

To make sure it exists do the following:

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $ino ) {
    if (isset($pumps[$ino])) { 
    ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        Name: <?php echo $pumps[$ino]['Title']; ?>  // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        Price: <?php echo $pumps[$ino]['Price']; ?> // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        Qty: <?php echo $_POST[$ino]['qty']; ?>  // error here
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type='submit' name='delete' value='<?php echo $ino; ? 
     >'>Remove</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    $total += $pumps[$ino]['Price']; // error here
   }
} // end foreach
?>
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted: please leave a comment why you think the answer is incorrect and you downvoted. Then i can adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: if fixed the  $_POST[$ino]['qty'] by just making it $_POST['qty']. The real problem is the $pumps[$ino]['Price']

Comment: $ino is equal to the id of the product

Comment: it is pointing to the wrong id, but i think i can fix it! thank you so much for your help man ! really appreciative of your help!